# Calculate Sent and Received PING Packets at run-time in Linux

Tags: linux, unix, ping

I have to calcuate sent and received PING packets at run-time in Linux. Now in Linux, even with verbose, nothing gets printed if packets are not received. Prints are only for successful replies, destination host unreachable.

How can sent and received packets be seen at run-time on the terminal? Any method by which this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution - if you want to see all sends and all receives is to actually make the source do that. The source for the ping command is widely available and can be edited to make it do what you want.

That said, if you don't want to actually edit the source, because it doesn't suit, you really should use the `-c` option, for the count of packets to send, and use the command to send **one at a time**. The return code from the command can be used to determine if a packet was seen, and you can use (roughly) the time that the command started at for the origin time of the packet.

Bear in mind ping it quite deterministic in it's behaviour. By default, it sends *one packet per second*, so you should be easily able to do the math based on how long it runs for and the count of packets you tried to use.